# Mariadb / mysql table partitionning column usage

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

I read mariadb documention :https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partition-maintenance/

And it sayed :

> The partition field should not be the field first in any key

But in mysql documentation :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

And exemples use the first field in key (unique key) for partitioning.

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
col1 INT NOT NULL,
col2 DATE NOT NULL,
col3 INT NOT NULL,
col4 INT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY (col1, col3)
)
PARTITION BY HASH(col1 + col3)
PARTITIONS 4;
```

So what is the trouble if the partition field is the first field of a key ?

Comment: You can find the explaination in [INDEXes in a PARTITIONed Table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) article: *If you choose to have the partition key in an index, it is usually (but not always) best to put the partition key last in any index. Note that the "pruning" is done before looking at the index, so the partition key is effectively used before the rest of the column(s) in the index.*

Comment: "should not" is only advisory (contrast "must not").

Comment: Notice that two of those links advise against ever using `PARTITION BY HASH`.  Elsewhere there is advice that you should always have a `PRIMARY KEY`.